# Use case-when statement in visual studio with mysql

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, select, case

I am trying to build a tableadaptor by using a mySQL query which includes a column as so:

```
if((`c`.`timed` > 0), 'Y', 'N') AS `Timed`,
```

This works when I run it in the MySQL workbench but causes an error in VS2012, which is unable to generate the select statement.

I have also tried using

```
case `c`.`timed` when 0 then 'Y' when 1 then 'N' end AS `Timed`,
```

with no sucess.

Can someone please tell me how this query should be written?

Thanks

FULL QUERY:

```
select 
    `c`.`callid` AS `callid`,
    concat(`cs`.`firstname`, ' ', `cs`.`lastname`) AS `Customer`,
    `c`.`postcode` AS `postcode`,
    `c`.`type` AS `type`,
if((`c`.`timed` > 0), 'Y', 'N') AS `Timed`,   `c`.`calldate` AS `calldate`,
`c`.`notes` AS `notes`,
    `c`.`driver` AS `Driver`
from
    (((`quick-quote-2`.`call` `c`
    left join `quick-quote-2`.`driver` `d` ON ((`c`.`driver` = `d`.`driverid`)))
    left join `quick-quote-2`.`booking` `b` ON ((`c`.`booking` = `b`.`bookingid`)))
    left join `quick-quote-2`.`customer` `cs` ON ((`b`.`customer` =  `cs`.`customerid`)))
where
    (`c`.`canx` = 0)
```

ERROR:

```
Error in list of function arguments: '>' not recognised
unable to parse query text
```

Comment: sorry - have added the select statement I am trying to use and the error I get

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if VS and the `IF()` function are causing the error but you can always use a `CASE` expression. This is the quivalent:

```
CASE WHEN `c`.`timed` > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS `Timed`,
```

Comment: Thanks. I already tried a CASE WHEN but copied your snippet above again just incase but still get an error - this time "Error in list of function arguments 'END' not recognised"

Comment: also to answer previous poster - I'm trying to do this in the tableadaptor configuration wizard.

Comment: Also realised that every time I try to modify the sql select query, the tableadaptor wizard adds the column 'calldate` again as 'calldate1', breaking a DGV that uses it.